# How to find a basis of $M_{2\times 2}$ consisting of invertible matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **Q.** There is a basis for $M_{2\times 2}$ consisting of invertible matrices.

I know the standard basis for this space but I can't find the invertible . . .

Answer (score 1):

I'll start you off with two matrices to give you an idea – see if you can find another two that will together make a basis.

$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\;\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix},\;\;{\huge ?}\;\;,\;\;{\huge ?}\;\;\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: think binary and flip bits.

Comment: I had to read your answer twice to understand what you meant, but besides that it's funny and exhaustive at the same time. (+1)